# What is the cheapest public transport option to get from Paris to Nicosia?

Tags: budget, public-transport, paris, cyprus

So it's just a sort of sport interest - I wonder how to get from Paris to Nicosia, Cyprus, spending as little money as possible but at the same time using transportation (because, obviously, otherwise bicycle or hitch-hiking could be a solution). I'm open to taking trains, buses, ferries etc.

Buying a plane ticket (Paris-Larnaca) will cost me about 260$.

Comment: Asking for cheapest transport solutions will inevitably lead to people suggesting hitch-hiking. Are you prepared to hitch?

Comment: @JoErNanO that's why i've mentioned transportation, I guess hitch-hiking is worser than just biking - in that case I'll just go biking )

Comment: Ok then if you are not prepared to hitch, add this to your question. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO done, thanks for helping to improve the question )

Comment: In fact, it's not bicycling, it's an inverted triathlon: Bicycle to the Mediterranean coast, swim to Cyprus and then run to Nikosia...

Comment: Personally, I would not consider other than flight when distance becomes significant. Are you ready to confront long hauls and several changes? I mean, a long journey of trains (Paris, Milan, Tirana, Athens) over 2 or 3 days and then ferry may be few bucks cheaper than flight, but **is it worth the physical effort**? Is it worth losing time in finding one such way? I was optimist in choosing the cities, the interconnections could even be more. Same said for buses. I am speaking this comment because I have seen a number of insane requests for cheapest way along exorbitant distances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Picking a random date in the future, [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris/Nicosia?dates=2015-2-18) shows that flying to Larnaca and then going by airport shuttle is probably the cheapest option in terms of paying.

However, if you're searching elsewhere for flights, check out both Larnaca and Ercan as options, and flying out of both CDG and ORY in Paris, as they seem to produce quite different prices.

Other than that, you're down to hitching or cycling - driving and taking a ferry looks extremely exorbitant!

Comment: it looks like indeed, nothing can beat flying through Ercan, I've managed to by ticket for ~90 euro.